# Restrict ETL query to not affect production - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am thinking of using Trino to extract data from production database (Postgres) and insert it into new table in another database (Postgres) which will be used only for analytics.

Since in this select-and-insert query, select part will query on production database and could affect production database load and thus the main product application.

Is there any way to restrict this select query to use only like 10-20% of memory/cpu/connection/any other runtime parameters on production database, so that other active users on product application using production database does not get affected ?

I am fine if this select query gets slow and take more time.

Edit-1: I want to copy entire or 70-80% of database production to analytics database

Comment: You could use a `read replica` for the production server, and then use that for copying over data to your destination db. You cannot restrict a specific query to use only x% of CPU, as far as I know. BTW, do you want to copy only 1 table from source, or the entire DB, it is not clear from your wordings.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran - I have edited the question. Read replica is already used in production for read-only queries. I read somewhere that Redshift has some settings to allow certain % of utilisation to specific user, so was wondering if same is available in postgres. And I want to copy from read replica to new db for analytics